# Plotting lists in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a matlab project:

[image]

We just started matlab, we haven't had any tutorials, just projects. We were giving a handout for it but it doesn't help. I'm really confused about this

Comment: If you did not code in Matlab before, just start with simple things. Search youtube for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTS5ZmrrzMs  This course series seems ok to me. If you'll have to use Matlab a lot, you have to learn it and in order to do this you need to do lots of simple examples. It is really easy, once you know the basic commands, but don't expect a magic recipe. Learning needs work, as always. Of course, it is not enough to read or watch tutorials. You need to do the actual coding yourself for a course to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function drawpattern(theta,n)
d = theta*pi/180; %convert to radians
R=[cos(d) sin(d); -sin(d) cos(d)];
p_last=[0;0];
x=zeros(1,n+1);
y=x;
figure;
hold on;
for i=1:n+1
    x(i)=p_last(1);
    y(i)=p_last(2);
    p_last=p_last+R^(i-1)*[i;0];
end
plot(x,y)
axis('equal')
box on
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know any notes that explain this better, I'm having a hard time finding good tutorials

Comment: Do you mean Matlab code? Just see Matlab documentation.

Comment: I know, that's part of what I've been using, they don't help that much but thanks either way